# How to use Eloquent to retrieve data from two different tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I'm setting up a system to check if the user has sent a message to another user.

**MessagesController.php**

```php
use App\Message;
use App\User;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.messages')->with('messages', Message::all())
                                     ->with('users', User::all());

    }
```

The message migration has following data:

```php
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('from');
            $table->integer('to');
            $table->mediumText('text');
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

And the web.php

```php
Route::get('/admin/messages', [
        'uses' => 'MessagesController@index',
        'as' => 'messages'
    ]);
```

So the idea is to present a panel with the data of messages, showing:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach ($messages as $message)

        <td>
            {{ $message->from}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $message->to}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $message->text}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $message->status}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $message->created_at}}
        </td>

        @endforeach
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This loads correctly all the information on the Message table. However, it will display the 'from' and 'to' as and ID, as it should.

I expect to have the table populated with not the ID of the user, but the Name of the user, via a relationship between the Message table and the Users table.

What am I missing?

Comment: from and too are user id right?

Comment: @mrhn That's right, both 'from' and 'to' are user ID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define your [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships). It looks like a `User` has many `Message`s, so:

**Message.php**

```
public function sender()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from');
}

public function receiver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to');
}
```

Note: Here I'm using two [`belongsTo` relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) with a custom foreign key, this is because Laravel will look for the `{model}_id` column by default, but this way Laravel will know the column to search for.

Then in your controller you can return your messages but [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationships that you need in order to be able to show them in your view:

```
use App\Message;
use App\User;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::with(['sender', 'receiver'])->get();

        return view('admin.messages')->with('messages', $messages);

    }
}
```

So then in your view:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    @foreach ($messages as $message)
        <td>
            {{ $message->sender->name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $message->receiver->name}}
        </td>

        // ...

    @endforeach
</tr>
</tbody>
```

---

### Observation

Given that primmary keys are positive integers, update your foreign key types to this:

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('from'); // <-----
        $table->unsignedInteger('to');  // <------
        $table->mediumText('text');
        $table->integer('status');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This will help you avoid some trouble in the future. Also, from Laravel `5.8` the primary keys are Big Increments by default. So in case you use those, your foreign keys should be like this: `$table->unsignedBigIncrement('column_name');`

Comment: I've done as you suggested but i'm getting a `ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property of non-object` on messages.blade.php

Comment: Turns out I had a table entry wtih an undefined relation, (there was a user in column 'to' with ID 1 and no user with ID 1 in the User table). It's fixed, and it works now, thank you for the help, it has become more clear now how access this data the Laravel way

Answer (score 1):

In your message model you will have to define relations. We define from and to relations, these will need an extra parameter to define what the key name is, as it is not part of the Laravel standard you are following.

```
public class Message
{
    public function from()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from');
    }

    public function to()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to');
    }
}
```

With this done, you will be able to do something similar like this.

```
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.messages')->with('messages', Message::all())
}
```

If access the user like this $message->from, you will get an object. If you access the method, you will get the query builder, like so $message->from().

Now you can utilise it in the blade template.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    @foreach ($messages as $message)
      <td>
        {{ $message->from->name}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ $message->to->name}}
      </td>

      ....
    @endforeach
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your solution worked too! Appreciated your help @mrhn

Comment: In general on stackoverflow if answers help you or is quality upvote them, not to get on my own but also on HCK's answer which clearly helped you.

Comment: Nice touch, @mrhn +1.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Sorry guys